# Many to many relation in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a serious problem for querying in many to many relationship.
I have fields such as Account number, api key, connection Id, priority, source ID, user Id, and Labels such as read, unread , starred( as such in gmail). 1 account Number may contain many usersId and 1 userId may be in different account Numbers. 
The task is if I enter the account Number, it should given the count(**count alone**) of users , read and unread messages. If the query is account Number with a userId, then it should display the count of read and unread message of that userId alone.

Like wise if any of the fields were queried, other fields should be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create a new Model or "table in the middle" that covers that relationship. For example:

```
class AccountUserRelation(db.Model):

    account = db.ReferenceProperty(Account,
                                   required=True,
                                   collection_name='users')

    user = db.ReferenceProperty(User,
                                required=True,
                                collection_name='accounts')
```

You can take a look into the official documentation. Here you can find some info about [Modeling Entity Relationships](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling), and read the 'Many to Many' section to get some ideas.